# Obtener un registro de una consulta

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Saludo, miembros de la comunidad.

He hecho una consulta DB::select y me devuelve un array con un solo registro, { [["llave" : "valor"]]}

```
$ciudad = BD::select(select * from ciudad where id='.$id.'');
```

Ciudad tiene un campo latitud, quiero obtener la latitud y darla a una variable como texto

Como obtengo se valor?

Comment: Cuál es la consulta `DB::select` o `Ciudad::find($i)`? Que valor tiene `$i`?

Comment: @JuanFelipeGonzalesSanchez, mejor muestranos todo el codigo, hay algo que no cuadra en tu pregunta y podria ser cerrada.

Comment: En principio indicas que realizas un `DB::select`, esta es una consulta hecha con `Query Builder`, que no es lo mismo de lo que después  muestras como codigo: `$ciudad = Ciudad::find($i);`, que esta hecha con `ORM` de laravel, que si bien parecen iguales, son totalmente diferentes.

Comment: Tienes razón, la consulta la hacen con DB

Comment: Es `DB` como dices en el comentario, de `Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB`, no `BD` como pusiste en el código.

Answer (score 1):

Genera un modelo llamada Ciudad y por medio del método find filtra, pues considero innecesario el usar el constructor de consultas para algo simple.

De este modo

```
$data = Ciudad::find($id);
```

Una vez hecho debería alcanzar con indicar objeto y propiedad

```
 $latitud =  $data->latitud;
```

Incluso yo optaría por sustituir el método `find` por el de `findOrFail()` para que en caso de no encontrar un registro entonces genere una excepción y retorne un 404

> En teoría no deberías requerir iterar los valores y en cambio solo acceder a la propiedad deseada

Answer (score 1):

Tienes 2 formas para hacerlo o tal vez no existe ese valor `latitud en tu DB`

**Primero [Query Builder as DB]**

```
//$ciudad = BD::table("ciudad")->find($id);
$ciudad = BD::table("ciudad")->where("id",$id)->first();

/*
json:     return $ciudad;
vista:    {{$ciudad->latitud}}
*/
```

**Segundo [Eloquent ORM]**

**Modelo CIUDAD**

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Ciudad extends Model{
    protected $table='ciudad';
    protected $primaryKey='id';
    public $timestamps=false;// si no usas created_at/updated_at, en caso de tenerlos 'true'
}
```

```
$ciudad = Ciudad::find($id);

/*
json:     return $ciudad;
vista:    {{$ciudad->latitud}}
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

Deberias poder acceder al valor de la siguiente forma:

```php
$ciudad->latitud
```

o

```php
foreach($ciudad as $ciu){
    $ciu->latitud   
}
```

Comment: Me da como respuesta "try to get property 'latitud' of non-object

Comment: Prueba con un foreach como lo coloque en la respuesta

Answer (score 0):

Una consulta en Laravel del tipo:

```
$ciudad = DB::select('SELECT * FROM ciudad WHERE id='.$id);
```

Te va a devolver un array con los resultados del SELECT. Como le estas indicando una `id`, solo te va a poder devolver un array vacío (si no encontró el registro) o con un solo registro (objeto) en su interior.

Podrías acceder al dato de esta forma:

```
$ciudad = DB::select('select * from ciudad where id='.$id);
$latitud = ($ciudad) ? $ciudad[0]->latitud : null;
```

donde estas comprobando que el array no está vacío antes de tratar de realizar la asignación o asignando *null* (por defecto) en caso de que no haya resultados (pon un 0, string vacío un el valor que consideres en ese caso).

Otro modo de hacer lo anterior es obtener la ciudad con el ORM, si has definido el modelo correspondiente:

```
$ciudad = Ciudad::find($i);
```

y obtener el valor de la propiedad de la ciudad:

```
$latitud = $ciudad->latitud;
```

Comment: No tienes un problema de comillas al final de tu primer sentencia?

Comment: @Aprendiz sí. Error por copiar y pegar sin probar las cosas...

Comment: También indicar que el facade correcto es `DB` no BD. Más info en https://laravel.com/api/6.x/Illuminate/Support/Facades/DB.html o https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/queries